# How do I include icon files when compiling my python code?

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, pyinstaller, nuitka

I am able to set the general Icon for the executable, however, I am having issues compiling the code correctly so that it displays the icon file when I call it for new windows with tkinter (like help, about, etc.).

My code looks like this:

```
Window.iconbitmap(r'snake.ico')
```

I appreciate the help! Thank you.

Comment: If the ico file is in the same directory of the executable, it should work.

Comment: That is true, however, if I want to deploy the exe then I'd prefer if I could just send one file.

Comment: Then you need to convert the ico to PNG image and embed it in the source file using base64 encoding.  Then use `.iconphoto()` instead of `.iconbitmap()`.

Comment: Hi acw, When trying to distribute the exe Windows detected it as as virus. I read somewhere that this might be due to the icon. Do you by any chance know the answer for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example of how to do it:

```
from tkinter import Tk

win = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "Any image file")

win.iconphoto(True, photo)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Your code will get `NameError: name 'PhotoImage' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help @acw1668! The answer is:

1. convert png or ico to base64 e.g. https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64
   (Other convert tools offer conversion for HTML etc. make sure to delete 'data:...' at the beginning. Use only the raw text).
2. 

```
Image_Data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQ='
window.iconphoto(True, tk.PhotoImage(data=Image_Data))
```

Comment: You don't need to decode the data, just use it directly: `tk.PhotoImage(data=data)`.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate all of your help! It finally worked! Always seems easy when you know the answer but I searched a couple of hours for this! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok That faced me but don't worry you can solve this I will proceed my solutions
and try to solve your problem I hope you solve your problem.

if you used to pyinstaller you can try this command:

> pyinstaller main.py --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon <"put the
> full path of the .ico"> --add-data

Then after the run command will produce a dist file open it and take a look at the exe file if give you an error try to take the .ico and put it inside the dist file.

if the above solution does not work you should try the following solution and hopefully will solve the problem.

go to your terminal and write this command to download auto-py-to-exe

> pip install auto-py-to-exe

now after downloading the auto-py-to-exe write in terminal the bellow command then enter

> auto-py-to-exe

then The GUI of the library will open. So following the steps bellow:

[image]

**Steps:**

```
1. click on browse and choose your script<main.py>

2. choose onefile to make it a one file

3. choose a hide console to get rid of the black window.

4. now Important to browse and choose your photo.ico

5. additional step if you have other images click on the additional file and click on add files and choose your photos.

6. now convert it to .exe file.
```

**After finishing will give you the Output file open it you will find the executed file open it and you will get an error so just take the icon photo and put it inside the Output file.**

Hopefully, this solves your problem and I wish I be helped, anyone.